# Bootstrap 3 not loading all class's when called by Ajax URL request, but some are executed

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I asked a question yesterday, not knowing exactly how to ask the question.  So here is my revised question.

I am using Bootstrap 3 and It is not loading all the classes completely when the Ajax function calls "LEADS_2020_CARD.PHP".  One of the comments on my previous question indicated that bootstrap 3 has a lot of class overrides.  I have searched and searched and there is not much on this topic.  If my issue is with class overrides, I just don't understand why it reads most classes, but ignores others on the "LEADS_2020_CARD.PHP" page, as the only CSS I have in "PHP_LOADER.PHP" is only related to my spinner ring.  Please help me understand, Thank You.

```
    php_loader.php

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" />

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >


    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>



    <body onload="loadingAjax('myDiv');" style="font-family:Lato;background:#222222">
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
    $("#"+div_id).html('<div class="center"><div class="ring"></div><br><br><font color="white" face="arial" size="4"><b>Searching<br><?php echo $total_table_rows ?> records<div onload="myTimer();" style="color:white" id="demo"></div> <br>Please Wait ...</b></font></div>');
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "leads_2020_card.php?",
    data: "State_Code_table="+State_Code_table + "&category="+category+"&longitude="+longitude+"&latitude="+latitude,
    success: function(msg){
    $("#"+div_id).html(msg);
    }
    });
    <script>

    <script>
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1);
    var count = <?php echo $my_count ?>;
    function myTimer() {
    if(count < <?php echo $max_count ?>) {
    $('.progress').css('width', count + "%");
    count += <?php echo $count_interval ?>;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.round(count) +"%";
    // code to do when loading
    } else if(count > <?php echo $max_count ?>) {
    // code to do after loading
    count = <?php echo $max_count ?>;
    }
    }
    </script>
```

And Here is my CSS for this loader page

```
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Montserrat';
      background: black;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .center {
      display: flex;
      text-align: center;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .ring {
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      animation: ring 2s linear infinite;
    }
    @keyframes ring {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        box-shadow: 1px 5px 2px #e65c00;
      }
      50% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        box-shadow: 1px 5px 2px #18b201;
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(0360deg);
        box-shadow: 1px 5px 2px #0456c8;
      }
    }
    .ring::before {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      content: "";
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    }
    span {
      color: #737373;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      line-height: 200px;
      animation: text 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    }
    @keyframes text {
      50% {
        color: black;
      }
    }
    </style>
    </head>
```

Comment: i can't see any bootstrap in the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry, I left that out of my question.  I edited the question to include the CDN's I am using on both pages

Comment: CSS aren't "ignored" by the browser. They're either being overwritten or not applied because due to incorrect selectors. Either should be viewable in developer tools on any modern browser. Post a link to the page and the styles that you feel are incorrect.